# Iterate over multiple IEnumerables dynamically (Linq Concat?)

Tags: c#, list

What is the best way to iterate dynamically over multiple IEnumerables at once? The lists are nested in a complex way. It is not a simple `List<List<Entity>>`

Example of desired behavior:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Entity>[]> submeshes = new Dictionary<int, List<Entity>[]>();

foreach(Entity e in submeshes.SelectMany(i = 1, i = 4).Select(o => o[0] , o2 => o2[2])).Concat()
{
    e.Update();
}

foreach(Entity e in submeshes.SelectAll().Select(o => o[0])).Concat()
{
    e.Update();
}
```

The problem is that each submesh consists of different lists and I need two cases.

1. I need a distinction in the Linq command for a specific mix of
   lists.
2. I need to iterate all lists.

Comment: Doesn't Concat do that already? AFAIK it doesn't start iterating through the second list until it's finished the first, or build all lists into an array or list. I'm still not sure what you're asking sorry. Apart from a small syntax change - it's `list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list6)`, or you could probably do it pairwise with `Enumerable.Concat(..)` - what's wrong with the code you've got in the question? Or is that what you were after?

Comment: It is "pseudo"-code and yet only the desired behavior. I was not sure, if the Concat() is using copy under the hood, what would be disastrous

Comment: "I need a distinction in the Linq command for a specific mix of lists" - what does that mean - can you explain / elaborate / give an example please? Your `e.Update()` doesn't seem to care where the entity came from. Do you just mean because you've got an array of lists of entities? Both the array bit and the list bit are enumerable so can be unwound with SelectMany().

Comment: And what are you trying to do with `.SelectMany(i = 1, i = 4).Select(o => o[0] , o2 => o2[2]))`? I appreciate it's pseudocode but I don't understand the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
var submeshes = new Dictionary<int, List<Entity>[]>();
```

i.e. we have a dictionary with values of arrays of lists of entities, and that you just want to extract the entities without e.g. knowing which dictionary entry they came from, I think you can just use two SelectMany()s:

```
submeshes.Values              // = value collection of arrays of lists of entities
         .SelectMany(a => a)  // = enumerable of lists of entities
         .SelectMany(a => a)  // = enumerable of entities
```

You can then iterate over the resulting enumerable and it will dynamically stitch together all the source lists as it goes, i.e. there's no copying or materializing into other collections along the way.

Comment: I was working with your answer and `SelectMany()` did indeed help me further. But I realized that I will need a ISet as return value, in order to use fast `Contains(x)`. So I cant use the Linq approach because it will require to "instantiate and copy" and I will fall back to a double reference system with one big set for all references and a list of sets for the submeshes. Changes have to be applied to both structures.

Comment: You can construct a new HashSet using the enumerable: this will save references only in the set and not clone the entity objects? You could also use Linq's ToDictionary() to build a new dictionary using the entity as a key, and storing some arbritrary value in each entry (e.g. 0, or false) that you're not going to use.

Comment: Yes, but in every update I will have to copy all references, even though its only the references. With the double reference solution, there is no copying involved at all, only double effort on add/remove, what is rare

Answer (score 0):

I ran a performance test and the concat + foreach really was performing bad. ListCombined would be a separate list that contains all lists in one. The fastest way would really be sequencially iterating over list1, list2, etc.. So my final solution would be a method, that run a generic method to invoke the same functions on multiple lists

[image]